# Python does not write all values of Key (JSON)

Tags: python, json

**Code:**

```
import json

data = open('data.json', 'r')
data = json.load(data)
x = open('test.txt', 'w')
for s in range(len(data)):
        print(data[s]["osm_id"])
        x.write(str(data[s]["osm_id"]) + "\n")
```

**JSON:**
https://openenergy-platform.org/api/v0/schema/openstreetmap/tables/osm_deu_point_windpower/rows/

**Problem:**
Not all values of "osm_id" are written into the TXT file, but only a small part. However, I want to have every single value of "osm_id" in the TXT file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should close your files once you have finished with them:

```py
import json

with open('data.json', 'r') as data:
    data = json.load(data)

with open('test.txt', 'w') as x:
    for s in range(len(data)):
        print(data[s]["osm_id"])
        x.write(str(data[s]["osm_id"]) + "\n")
```

Comment: It writes about 500 values more, but thats not everything...

Comment: I can't tell exactly how many, but it must start with the first osm_id and with the last and it doesnt with the script

Comment: Ok, what are the first and last values you are expecting?

Comment: @zTrusted what version of python are you using?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 3.8.2

Comment: @zTrusted well there is no reason why the above code shouldn't work.. you can't tell exactly how many, btw, by `print(len(data))`

Comment: @quamrana first: 1257757178, last: 1213003450
the file is linked above

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what I get.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Looks like it does not though, because the txt file's first line isn't 1257757178 and the last is not 1213003450

Comment: @zTrusted Well, then there is something in that code you aren't showing us. Are you *sure* you are using python 3.8? Put `import sys` then put `print(sys.version_info)` at the end of the script, as well as `print(len(data))`... What does it give you?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga
print(len(data)) = 3500
print(sys.version_info) =sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Comment: I downloaded over 24000 items from the link you provided.

Comment: @quamrana
how many lines are in your txt file then? I've got 3500 and thats not all, it must be around 24,600

Comment: I have one line in the text file per id. So about 24600 lines.

Comment: How did you copy the data from the link to your json file? Chrome took a while to display it all. Did you copy it before your browser had downloaded it all?

Comment: @quamrana That's weird. Im getting 3500 on vsc and on repl.it
Are you sure?

Comment: @quamrana I downloaded it and use it as a file with open()

Comment: I think you can take everything I post as absolutely true.

Comment: @quamrana Just tried to grab it on the website and that works, but it doesn't work when I download it. I'll take your answer as a solution :) Thanks